# Hide a DIV when displayed in a specific DIV

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to hide a DIV, but only when it is displayed in another div.
I have a Contact Form that I display in two places, in a sidebar and on a contact page. This is my form that is displayed using PHP include.

```
<div class="contact_details_div">
    <h3>Some Text</h3>
    Some additional text
</div>
<div class="contact_div">
    <form id="contact_form" action="" method="post" target="_self">
        MY FORM IS HERE    
    </form>
</div>
```

In my sidebar, the form is displayed like this:

```
echo "<div class=\"contact_form_sidebar\">";
include("inc/contact_form.inc.php");
echo "</div>";
```

And, my Contact page it's displayed like this:

```
echo "<div class=\"contact_form_full\">";
include("inc/contact_form.inc.php");
echo "</div>";
```

I've tried to hide the class 'contact_details_div when it is displayed in the sidebar, but I can't seem to get it done.  This is my CSS:

```
/*CONTACT FORMS*/
/*FULL FORM*/
    .contact_form_full {
        position: relative;
    }
/*SIDEBAR FORM*/
    .contact_form_sidebar {
        position: relative;
    ]
    .contact_form_sidebar .contact_details_div {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Does anyone see an issue?  I can't, but I've been staring at it too long and am probably missing something simple.

Thanks!
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have square brackets instead of curly on line 9 in css.

Comment: In '.contact_form_sidebar'

Comment: Alexander, you the man!!!  See, I knew if a fresh pair of eyes looked it over the issue would be found.  I must have looked at that stupid square bracket a hundred times and my eyes told me it was a French bracket.  Thank you, thank you!!!